# Batch file throws error but when each command is run individually in command line it works fine

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My batch file is throwing error when run, but when I run the commands one by one manually in command line then I get no error. Here's the batch file 'test.bat'.

```
echo "test"
cd "c:\packages"
pause
for /R c:\packages %F in (*.msi) do set /A servername=%~nxF
pause
echo %servername%
pause
```

I get this error - "~nxF was unexpcted at this time".

I got the sample code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100466/1105556
I'm just trying the get the file name in c:\packages & store the value in 'servername' variable. There is only one file (.msi) in the folder
I cant figure out whats wrong. Can someone please solve the riddle for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double the `%%` in batch files:

```
for /R c:\packages %%F in (*.msi) do set /A servername=%%~nxF
```

Comment: Also, `set /A` evaluates the RHS as an arithmetic expression, which probably isn't wanted.

Comment: Thank you Ken & @arx. Took both suggestions & it worked. Just out of curiosity what is RHS. I googled it but couldn't find any thing relevant

Comment: @Sudhakar: `RHS` = `Right Hand Side`. `/A` takes everything to the right of it and tries to use it as an arithmetic expression (eg., `1 + 1 * 3`

Comment: Thank you Ken. Appreciate your time.

Comment: It works ! But can you tell me why we have to add double % on batch file?

Comment: @KailashDabhi Because that's the way it works. :-) From the command line you use one `%`, from a batch file you double them. (It's most likely a need to escape them when being run by the batch process portion of cmd.exe.)