# Read directories and split path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

To list the directories I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711180/how-to-list-all-folder-with-size-via-batch-file):

```
set folder=C:\temp
for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    echo %%~fa
)
```

To splith the file path I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279114/split-path-and-take-last-folder-name-in-batch-script):

```
for %%f in (%MYDIR1%) do set myfolder=%%~nxf
echo %myfolder%
```

Now I want put both together:

```
@echo off

set folder=C:\Windows

for /d %%A in ("%folder%\*") do (
    for %%d in (%%~fA) do set lastfolder=%%~nxf
    echo %lastfolder%
)
```

All I get in thes result is `%~nxf`. I tried some things, but I didn't get a correct result. What I'm doing wrong?

What I don't understand in these examples is `%~fA` and `%~nxf`. Don't know where you can look up things like this.

**Edit:**

`%~nxf` [to get file names with extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100452/get-filename-in-batch-for-loop#comment915359_1100466)

> where F is the variable and ~n is the request for its name | [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100466)

`%~fI` [Expands %I to a fully qualified path name.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Now I modified my code with the new information:

```
@echo off

for /d %%A in ("%folder%\*") do (
    for %%D in (%%~fA) do (
        set lastfolder=%%~nxD
        echo %lastfolder%
    )
)
```

Now I get as result the last folder, but this is printed as many times as subfolders are existing. So I only get the last one. How can I iterate over each?

**Solution:**

Thanks to bgalea this is my solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set folder=C:\Windows

for /d %%A in ("%folder%\*") do (
    for %%D in (%%~fA) do (
        set lastfolder=%%~nxD
        echo !lastfolder!
    )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Dump this batch and convert it into Windows scripting ...

Comment: You mean Windows Script Host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things in bracket are one line. Therefore you have to use `!var!` which you turn on with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. See `set /?` and `setlocal /?`.

`.` is current directory and `..` is parent directory.

So `c:\temp\..` is the same as `c:\`

`%~nx1` etc are documented in the call command's help - `call /?`

My answer here [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch) has a list of command prompt punctuation.

Comment: Have you seen my edit? I tried it with `enabledelayedexpansion` and without but the results were the same.

Comment: Have to use `!lastfolder!` not `%lastfolder%`

Comment: Reason why is that a variable name with exclamation marks is a valid MSDos variable. Hence having to turn on a special mode.