# Batch file: Pass file name to sub from FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

This question is about the correct syntax for passing file name arguments to a subroutine in a batch file. Feels like this question should have been asked before, but I can't seem to find the right answer. Assume there are three text files in a folder called `C:\Batch File Example`. The following code (partly borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100466)) will output the file names:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL Enableextensions

ECHO Line before FOR
FOR /R "C:\Batch File Example\" %%i in (*.txt) DO ECHO %%i
ECHO Line after FOR & PAUSE>NUL
```

Output:

```
Line before FOR
C:\Batch File Example\File1.txt
C:\Batch File Example\FIle2.txt
C:\Batch File Example\File3.txt
Line after FOR
```

Now, I want to produce the same output by using a subroutine instead, like this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL Enableextensions

ECHO Line before FOR
FOR /R "C:\Batch File Example\" %%i in (*.txt) DO CALL :doecho %%i
ECHO Line after FOR & PAUSE>NUL
GOTO :EOF

:doecho
SET VAR=%1
ECHO VAR is %VAR%
EXIT /b
```

But this gives the following output, where the result is truncated:

```
Line before FOR
VAR is C:\Batch
VAR is C:\Batch
VAR is C:\Batch
Line after FOR
```

The result above suggests that whitespace is treated as a delimiter and that `%1` only contains `C:\Batch`, so I tried using the following for loop instead, with the `/F`flag and a comma delimiter to suppress the whitespace:

```
FOR /F "delims=," %%i IN ("C:\Batch File Example\*.txt") DO CALL :doecho %%i
```

However, this also returns the truncated result, with the only difference that there is only one iteration instead of three.

I've tried using [enhanced variable substitionts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112120) like `%~I` instead of `%%i` and `%1`, but I'm stuck. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

parameters are separated by spaces - so `C:\Batch File Example\file.txt` are *three* parameters (more, if the filename also contains spaces).

Either use `%*` ("all parameters") instead of `%1` or use quotes: `... CALL :doecho "%%I"`, then it's a single (quoted) parameter. If you need to remove the quotes in your subroutine, use `%~1`

Comment: Great, both alternatives work like a charm. Not very intuitive... Btw, any insight into why the for loop with the `/F` flag only iterated once?

Comment: @Egalth If you look at `for /?`, you'll see that you are using the `for /f ... in ("string") ...` variant. This runs the loop _once_ with just the value of `string` parsed into the loop-variable(s). In your case, that single value is `C:\Batch File Example\*.txt` which -- as explained above -- will pass just `C:\Batch` into `%1` of `doecho`.

Comment: @TripeHound, good point, thanks! @Stephan's solution will indeed work with the following syntax, without any command extension: `FOR %%i IN ("C:\Batch File Example\*.txt") DO CALL :doecho "%%i"`.