# how to determine name of an exe file using wild card character and execute that file in cmd/batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a project which builds an application and whenever it builds the application the names it generates are like this MyApp1.1.exe, myapp1.2.exe, myApp,1.3.exe etc. I would like to deploy the application in another environment whenever there is a new build. But the problem is that I'm using the following in command in the batch script, which is is keep throwing me an error

```
MyApp1.*.exe
```

But it always throws an error in the command line saying that 'MyApp1.*.exe' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I know that this should be very simple but I could not seem to find any solution

Comment: At the same time as you create the `MyApp.a.b.exe`, also create a `MyApp.latest.bat` that just runs this newly created version.

Comment: You cannot use the * wildcard operator to select a single file. You will need to use batch scripting and a for loop, similar to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100452/get-filename-in-batch-for-loop/1100466).

Comment: no, you can't do that. in `cmd` do `for %i in (MyApp*.exe) do start "" "%~i"`. double up on the `%` when used from batch-file.

Comment: What documentation did you find in a book or online that says you can use that syntax in a batch file? Would like to know for my own documentation purposes.

Comment: @Gerhard Thank you. It actually worked :)

Answer (score 1):

`cmd`, which is used to run `batch-files`, requires that you run `for` loops to do something `for` each item. You therefore need to give `for` some criteria and it will return the list based on that. You can then `do` something with these metavariables.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (MyApp*.*.exe) do echo start "" "%%~i"
```

For the purpose of this demonstration, I am not actually running the `exe`cutable's, instead I just `echo` the full command. If you feel that it is suitable for this purpose, then simpy remove `echo` from the `echo start ""..` section.

Comment: Yeah, it should, that is why I posted the answer :)